# How to empty a gridview on Android?

Tags: android, gridview, icons, double

I am developping a launcher with two different profiles : one is the main one the other is secondary. If I go on the play store and then come back with the "back" button, I land on my main profile, but there, the icons of my gridview (displayed through an adapter) appear in double (if I install two apps from the play store, coming back with the back button will give me icons 3 times and so on).

If I restart my main activity in the onresume method, things go fine and my icons aren't doubled, or tripled or whaterver. 
But I don't want to restart the activity, I only want to empty my gridview.

```
if((admin == true) ){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);}
```

Comment: Have you try `adpater.clear()` and the `adapter.notifyDataSetchanged()` or simply `gridview.removeAllViews()`  ?

Comment: @Pragnani Calling `removeAllViews()` on a `GridView` throws exception.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem myself. The easiest way to do this is:

```
gridview.setAdapter(null);
```

Comment: `setAdapter()` calls `removeAllViewsInLayout()`

Answer (score 3):

you can put your data to be loaded with gridview into a list, then when you want to update your gridview ,just use

```
    list.clear();
```

then reload your updated data to your list,set adapter again.Here below shows my code:

I use gridview to load images from web,fetched by Asynctask;when I want to update those images when back from setting to my Fragment/Activity,  I clear the list containing data and refilling work is done in AsyncTask.

```
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    list.clear();
    //setAdapter(null) is not useful here after testing.
    SharedPreferences preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String sort_order=preferences.getString("pref_sortOrder","popular");
    ParseDataTask parseDataTask=new ParseDataTask();
    parseDataTask.execute(sort_order);
    }
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove items from adapter of the GridView. You can obtain adapter by calling [#getAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#getAdapter%28%29)
You may need to implement cleaning method in adapter if it not exist. If adapter extends [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) you may need to call [#notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)